# scanf() asking for input twice

Tags: c, scanf

I tried getting rid of spaces and newline characters but to no avail, it still asks for input twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  double a = 0;
  double b = 0;
  double c = 0;
  //controls wether a is a number
  int controllo1 = 1;
  while (controllo1 = 1) {
    printf("insert x^2");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    getchar();
    if (scanf("%lf", &a)) {
      getchar();
      printf("input  is a number\n");
      controllo1 = 0;
      break;
    }
    else
      printf("input is not a number\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: And you are expecting it to .... ?

Comment: With `%lf` you don't *need* to get rid of whitespace in the input. It's automatically filtered except with specifiers `%c` and `%[]` and `%n`. And with those, you can place a space immediately before the `%` to filter any amount of leading whitespace. No need for `getchar()` kludges.

Comment: Considering that you have used `scanf("%lf",&a)` twice it is unsurprising that the program wants input twice..

Comment: that is right. i just thought the scanf inside the if was its own thing, i'm very new at this and it shows, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @GioBur: Please self-answer then. It's clear you now understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are two scanf functions in the program, which understandably asks for input twice. Removing the one in line 12 will solve the issue.